# Добавление и удаление значений в QVector

Tags: c++, qt

Мне нужно  написать функции  которые добавляют и удаляют значения в QVector.

Я создаю вектор

```
QVector<std::unique_ptr<Category>> mCategories;
```

Создаю две функции:

```
 void Category::addCategory(std::unique_ptr<Category> category)
 {
     mCategories.push_back(category);
 }
 void Category::removeCategory(int categoryIndex)
 {
     mCategories.remove(categoryIndex);
 }
```

Ошибка:

```
D:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore\qvector.h:641: error: C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<Task,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
with
[
_Ty=Task
]
```

Но я не понимаю почему выдает, нужна ваша помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объекты `std::unique_ptr` являются некопируемыми, однако являются перемещаемыми, соответственно вместо копирования их следует перемещать:

```
mCategories.push_back(::std::move(category));
```